# WPF DataGrid rows shuffling after sort

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, mvvm, datagrid

I have DataGrid which fully MVVM implemented. I noticed that when I sort a column and that column has several rows with the same value, the rows keep on getting shuffled. Let me explain with the below example :

```
CAR | Brand | Color
-------------------
 1  | Honda | Red
 2  | Ford  | Blue
 3  | GMC   | Red
```

If I sort this table by "Color". The sort will be good but the rows 1 and 3 will keep on changing/swapping.

I must say that my ViewModel has a thread to update the data continuously. Basically, that thread does this after querying for the data :

```
mCollectionViewSource.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send,
  new Action(delegate()
  {
    if (!mObservableCollection.Contains(newDataObject))
    {
      mObservableCollection.Add(newDataObject);
    }
    else
    {
      int index = mObservableCollection.IndexOf(newDataObject);
      mObservableCollection[index] = newDataObject;
    }
  }));
```

Comment: You should only update data when there is a change in it. Use events and listeners, don't "poll" it.

Comment: Yes, future development. But anyway, implementing this won't fix that problem right? Cause next time there is an update, the rows will shuffle. It will just happen fewer times...

Comment: It's a must, and in the future it will only be a bigger change (= a bigger problem, a bigger headache). Do it now. Also, it isn't "harder" than your current approach, so there is no reason for you not to go with it in the first place and prevent problems such as this.

Comment: Just for the information, may i know how do you logically differentiate two instance of your data object(newDataObject) ?

Comment: If it doesn't solve your problem (and I believe that it might), just use a more clever sort on your rows. Sort by Color, and then by ID. If all ID's are different, this assures that only one order can exist per two rows when they have the same Color.

Comment: @nair I override Equals. Its a Custom object.

Comment: That's not enough. Since most cases the sort is performed through IComparable (if there one) implementation. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx

Comment: In MVVM, the sort gets applied to the View not the ItemsSource. Am I right? That to say that I have tried what you suggest and the CompareTo is never called.